# PHP SQL update multiple rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am stuck in a very crucial part of my project and would like some help - however I seem to be stuck in the PHP / SQL syntax and cannot get the query to work.

HTML code:

```
<form name="homepage" method="POST" action="" >
   <p>Page Title</p>
  <input id="pagetitle" type="text" name="home_title" value="<?php select_text("SELECT fieldcontent FROM content WHERE name='home_title'", "fieldcontent") ?>"/>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <textarea id="paragraph" name="home_text"><?php select_text("SELECT fieldcontent FROM content WHERE name='home_text'", "fieldcontent") ?>  </textarea>
    <h1>Images</h1>
    <div id="image">
    <?php select_image("SELECT * FROM `image` WHERE image_cat_id = 8"); ?>
    </div>
    <button name="homesavebtn" id="home-save-btn" type="submit">Save Updates</button>
</form>
```

PHP code - Select data

```
function select_text($sql, $echo) {
include 'connect.php';

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row[$echo];
    $conn->close(); 
  } 
}
```

PHP code - update

```
if ($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['homesavebtn'])){
$home_title = (isset($_POST['home_title']) ? $_POST['home_title'] : null);
$home_text = (isset($_POST['home_text']) ? $_POST['home_text'] : null); 

include 'connect.php';

 $sql = "INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) VALUES ('home_title', '$home_title') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = '$home_title'"; 
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) VALUES ('home_text', '$home_text') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = '$home_text'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "";
} else {
echo "" . $sql . "<br>" .mysqli_error($conn);
} 
$conn->close();

}
}
```

Getting the following error:

> INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) VALUES ('home_title', 'Mosta Cycling Club') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = 'Mosta Cycling Club'INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) VALUES ('home_text', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = ''
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) VALUES ('home_text', '') ON DUPLICATE KE' at line 1

Comment: Please add a description of the problem you are having - what specifically is going wrong with what you have at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `VALUES` to get the new value you are using in the update portion.  Also, if you use `prepare` and `bind_param` you will prevent SQL injection:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) 
                          VALUES ('home_title', ?), ('home_text', ?)
                          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = VALUES(fieldcontent)");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $home_title, $home_text);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Mysqli needs a type argument to `bind_param`, doesn't it?

Comment: What is the meaning of 'ss' in $stmt->bind_param('ss', $home_title, $home_text); ?

Comment: Each s says the type of a parameter is a string

Answer (score 0):

Your second SQL statement is being added to your first creating one long statement that doesn't make sense. Separate these into two different statements.